# How do I use two different custom UITableViewCell subclasses in a single table?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How to I properly display to different UITableViewCell subclasses within the same UITableView?

I am using the storyboard for this question. I am trying to use two different subclasses of UITableView cell in a single table. The idea that `TTTextFieldCell`s know how to show a text box and `TTPickerCell`s know how to present a UIPicker to the user. There the protocol `TTTableViewCell` specifies a single selector: `[setCellDetails (NSDictionary*) cellDetails]` Each `UITableViewCell` subclass knows what to do with the cellDetails Dictionary to setup the cell.

```
-(NSArray *)tableData {
     if (!_tableData) {
          _tableData =
          @[ // Sections
             @{ // Section Details
                  kSectionName:@"Scout Information"
                  ,kRows:@[ // Rows
                             @{// Cell Details
                                  kBoundProperty:self.scoutName
                                  ,kReuseIdentifier:kTextFieldCell
                                  ,kLabel:@"Name"
                                  ,kPlaceholderValue:@"Scout's Name"
                                  }
                             ,@{
                                  kReuseIdentifier:@"TTPickerCell"
                                  ,kLabel:@"Type"
                                  ,kPlaceholderValue:@"Cadet, Junior, etc..."
                                  }
                             ,@{
                                  kBoundProperty:self.yearsScouting
                                  ,kReuseIdentifier:kTextFieldCell
                                  ,kLabel:@"Years"
                                  ,kPlaceholderValue:@"Years of Experience"
                                  ,kKeyboardStyle:@(UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad)
                                  }
                             ]
                  }
             ,@{ // Section Details
                  kSectionName:@"Parent Information"
                  ,kRows:@[
                             @{
                                  kBoundProperty:self.parentName
                                  ,kReuseIdentifier:kTextFieldCell
                                  ,kLabel:@"Name"
                                  ,kPlaceholderValue:@"Parents's Name"
                                  }
                             ]
                  }
             ];
     }
     return _tableData;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // Line A
     [self.tableView registerClass:[TTTextFieldCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TTTextFieldCell"];
    // Line B
     [self.tableView registerClass:[TTPickerCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TTPickerCell"];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSDictionary* cellDetails = self.tableData[indexPath.section][kRows][indexPath.row];

     NSString* reuseIdentifier = cellDetails[kReuseIdentifier];

     // Line C
     UITableViewCell<TTTableViewCell> *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

     [cell setCellDetails:cellDetails];
     return cell;
}
```

Now, here is the question. If I comment out line A and B, then the TTTextFieldCells are displayed correctly. But Line C will fail because it is attempting to call the TTTextFieldCell init with a TTPickerCell object, and failing because the TTPickerCell object doesn't have the same properties. If I uncomment Line A and B then the cell styles default to `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` and they don't display the custom controls. Oddly, if I comment out Line A, and uncomment line B, then the `TTTextFieldCells` look great, but the `TTPickerCells` default to `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`.

It seems that if I do not register a class, dequeue will return an instance of the first prototype cell class. If I register the class then the cell defaults to `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`.

Also of note, the initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: selectors only get called if the class is registered.

So, how to I properly display to different UITableViewCell subclasses within the same UITableView? Do I have to forgo using the storyboard to design the cell?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I found to be the answer.

1. Do not register the class for the reuse identifier. Comment out lines A and B.
2. Do not copy and paste prototype cells, unless you take great care to review the IBOutlets. The pasted prototype cell doesn't care what UITableViewCell subclass you assign it too, it doesn't validate the IBOutlets are present.

Fixed up #2 and all was well.

Doh!

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to be calling `tableView registerClass:...` inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Instead, you should be registering your classes/nibs a single time. This is often done in the controller's `viewDidLoad` method. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation can then look something like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary* cellDetails = self.tableData[indexPath.section][kRows][indexPath.row];

    NSString *reuseIdentifier = (/*some condition*/ ? @"TTTextFieldCell" : @"TTPickerCell");
    UITableViewCell<TTTableViewCell> *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    [cell setCellDetails:cellDetails];
    return cell;
}
```

EDIT: I should mention `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always returns a cell from iOS 6 on. If you are targeting an earlier version of iOS you need to account for creating cells in the even this method returns nil.

Comment: Thank you @Alex. It is worth noting that this did not change the expressed behavior. :( But It makes good sense to register in the viewDidLoad method. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score -1):

I used 2 types of cells loaded from NIB and NSMutable array with my objects, objects have texts, titles and imagens that i want to use in cells. In method cellForRowAtIndexPath... u put content from objects to cell. U can init without nib.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (your condition){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellClass1" owner:self options:nil];
        CellClass1  *cell =  (CellClass1 *)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }else{
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellClass2" owner:self options:nil];
        CellClass2  *cell =  (CellClass2 *)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];}

        //get your content for cell at array or your own estructure 
        Content *content = [contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        cell.description.text = content.description;

        return cell;
    }
```